# how to enter inputs 10 times for a list of different questions

Tags: python, input, data-structures, tuples

i want to enter 10 inputs at one time for questions

```
Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5, Q6, Q7, Q8, Q9, Q10= str(input("Enter answers separating by space: ")).split()

print("Q1", Q1) 
print("Q2", Q2) 
print("Q3", Q3) 
print("Q4", Q4) 
print("Q5", Q5) 
print("Q6", Q6) 
print("Q7", Q7) 
print("Q8", Q8) 
print("Q9", Q9)
print("Q10", Q10)
```

I intend to have this as an outcome and i'm stuck not knowing what to put
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOhc5.png). does anyone know a shortcut way instead of typing "print()"/printing it out 10 times?

Comment: Do you need 10 inputs for each question or one input per question?

Comment: How your questions behave, one idea would be to produce a dictionary of key = question, value = answer.

Comment: "Do you need 10 inputs for each question or one input per question?" the latter

Answer (score 2):

Use a `list` of answers:

```
answers = []
for i in range(0, 10):
    answers.append(str(input('Q', ))
```

```
print(answers)  # ["answer_1", "answer_2", ..., "answer_10"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
answers = [str(input('Q', ) for _ in range(0, 10)]
```